# Calling PHP includes via a site path

Tags: php, path, root, global

I've been researching for 2 days and cannot find an answer that works.

This is my file structure.

```
/ucdev/ (index and future files)
/ucdev/classes/ (Classes)
/ucdev/users/ (all the user-related docs,account settings etc)
/ucdev/users/models/ (all the other config and db files, for now).
```

I need to figure out some way to load all my classes that is independent of what folder I'm calling the includes from. Basically I need to establish a site root variable that works.

I got the closest using

```
$subfolder = "/ucdev/"; 
$root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$subfolder;
```

But Chrome treats that $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] as a local c:\ type path and won't let me load resources (i.e. Not allowed to load local resource error in Chrome"

So, basically I need a way to have my config.php file have something like...

```
require_once ($root."classes/Session.php");
require_once ($root."classes/Token.php");
require_once ($root."classes/User.php");
```

and have those resources load whether or not that config.php was being pulled from

```
ucdev/index.php
or
ucdev/users/login.php
```

I hope I gave enough info to make sense.

Finally, one of the MOST IMPORTANT things is that I somehow wind up with a "root path" variable so I can call all of my links from root instead of relative to the file calling them.  I would like my top navigation to work regardless of what file is calling it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: I really do appreciate the link to documentation, but I've been reading documentation for days. If you could give me an example of how to change my code to work, that would be awesome.

Comment: $root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
define('root',str_replace("\\","/",$root) ."/");
require_once (root."classes/Session.php");

Comment: THAT 
define('root',str_replace("\\","/",$root) ."/"); was the trick! Without that, it just never worked consistently! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way to do this was to:

```
$subfolder = "/ucdev/";
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$subfolder);
define('root',str_replace("\\","/",$root) ."/");
```

Then when I include my classes I use

```
require_once (root."classes/Config.php");
```

and they work from anywhere.

For images and links that are located relative the root I can do things like...

```
img src="<?php root; ?>images/logo.png"
```

Thanks so much to Lucky Chingi for pointing me in the right direction!